# parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using PHP for the first time. I am using the php sample for uploading image on ebay sandbox. I am getting the following error on running the PHP file:

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/nish/stuff/market place/test/php5/UploadImage/UploadSiteHostedPictures.php on line 69
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): HTTP/1.1 200 OK in /home/nish/stuff/market place/test/php5/UploadImage/UploadSiteHostedPictures.php on line 69
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/nish/stuff/market place/test/php5/UploadImage/UploadSiteHostedPictures.php on line 69
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/nish/stuff/market place/test/php5/UploadImage/UploadSiteHostedPictures.php on line 92
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/nish/stuff/market place/test/php5/UploadImage/UploadSiteHostedPictures.php on line 93
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/nish/stuff/market place/test/php5/UploadImage/UploadSiteHostedPictures.php on line 93
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/nish/stuff/market place/test/php5/UploadImage/UploadSiteHostedPictures.php on line 94
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/nish/stuff/market place/test/php5/UploadImage/UploadSiteHostedPictures.php on line 94
```

Relevant lines are:

```
69. $respXmlObj = simplexml_load_string($respXmlStr);     // create SimpleXML object from string for easier parsing
                                                      // need SimpleXML library loaded for this

92. $ack        = $respXmlObj->Ack;
93. $picNameOut = $respXmlObj->SiteHostedPictureDetails->PictureName;
94. $picURL     = $respXmlObj->SiteHostedPictureDetails->FullURL;
```

What I can understand is the respXMLObj is not getting set properly. I have checked that simleXML support is enabled.

Could someone please help me debug this. Thanks

Comment: The `$respXmlStr` holds an invalid XML.

Comment: Can you show your XML? Looks a invalid ones with missing "<" at the beginning.

Comment: @mcuadros : I am getting the XML as a response to an http request

Comment: @nish, yes but you are putting the raw reply (including the HTTP headers) into the XML parser. Don't use a socket, but a HTTP client instead.

Comment: His string begins with "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" apparently.

Comment: You must strip the HTTP headers.

Comment: @nish how do you get the reply?

Comment: @BartFriederichs `$respXmlStr = $session->sendHttpRequest($fullPost);`

Comment: @nish what kind of class is that?

Comment: @BartFriederichs : How else should I be doing it? Could you please share

Comment: @BartFriederichs : actually none of this is written by me. It a sample code that I'm running, found [here](https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1092)

Comment: @nish, set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to false in the class definition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code you refer to has this line:

```
//curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 ); // Uncomment these for debugging
```

it seems like you uncommented these. This will result in getting the HTTP header in your response. Which is OK for debugging, but it will create an XML parse error in `simplexml_load_string`.

Either comment it out again or put `0` as its value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `simplexml_load_file('localpath')` instead of `simplexml_load_string()`. I have had the same problem today (9 years later), and this was my solution.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I just **removed the invisible character The BOM** in the beginning of the XML file. How to do it - depends on your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
$hasError = false;

if ( $resp == 'Internal Server Error' || empty($resp) )
{
    $hasError = true;
}

if ( ! $hasError )
{                      
    $aux    = !empty($resp) ? explode('ï»¿', $resp) : NULL;
    $temp   = utf8_decode(trim($aux[0]));               
    $xml    = simplexml_load_string($temp); 
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code might be an answer to the question it would be much more useful if you [edit] it to add some explanation of the code and how it answers the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Do a `var_dump($respXmlStr);` my guess is that this string is not valid XML.

As per the simplexml-load-string documentation, the first parameter is expected to be `A well-formed XML string` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php