# Error when parsing the webservice response in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, simplexml, soap-client

I am at the learning stage of PHP. I have tried to invoke a sample webservice from a single PHP script.
I started with StockQuote service. Below is the script I have written.

```
<?php
   echo "Stock Quote service check";
   require_once 'nusoap.php';
   $wsdl="http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdl";
   $client=new SoapClient($wsdl);

   $param=array('symbol'=>'GOOG');  
   $response = $client->__soapCall('GetQuote', array($params));
   $quotes = simplexml_load_string($response->GetQuoteResult);

   echo $quotes;
   //->Stock[0];

   ?>
```

Below is the warning i got:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\wamp\www\nusoap.php on line 7384
>
> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   C:\wamp\www\nusoap.php on line 75
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: params in C:\wamp\www\URLExample.php on
>   line 8
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start
>   tag expected, '<' not found in C:\wamp\www\URLExample.php on line 9
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): exception in
>   C:\wamp\www\URLExample.php on line 9
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\wamp\www\URLExample.php on
>   line 9
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\URLExample.php on line 11

When I am invoking the function manually I got the below output.
[image]

Please help to parse the response XML to get the < Stock> value.
I found similar type of questions ([Question No: #22060990](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060990/php-warning-simplexml-load-string-entity-line-1-parser-error-start-tag-e)) but nothing helps to my situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @Jonast92- The question clearly mentioned that none of the other post are not exactly matching this situation.

Comment: that doesn't mean you're right -- this is indeed a pure duplicate, if you'd care to read the duplicate answer. Glad you got your stuff solved tho.

Comment: @Jonast92 - Its not about i want to get into a duplicate question. But i want the answer because i already gone through the other questions and nothing brings me the answer.
Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code, "$param" should be "$params",

Also, echo $quotes wont work because $quotes is a SimpleXML object, so you need to access it as an object($quotes->Stock->Last for example)

```
<?php
echo "Stock Quote service check";
require_once 'nusoap.php';
$wsdl="http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdl";
$client=new SoapClient($wsdl);
$params=array('symbol'=>'GOOG');  
$response = $client->__soapCall('GetQuote', array($params));
$quotes = simplexml_load_string($response->GetQuoteResult);
echo $quotes->Stock->Last;
?>
```

You can get following data from $quotes->Stock object:

```
["Symbol"]=>
string(4) "GOOG"
["Last"]=>
string(6) "528.48"
["Date"]=>
string(8) "2/2/2015"
["Time"]=>
string(6) "4:00pm"
["Change"]=>
string(5) "-6.04"
["Open"]=>
string(6) "531.44"
["High"]=>
string(6) "533.00"
["Low"]=>
string(6) "518.55"
["Volume"]=>
string(7) "2842249"
["MktCap"]=>
string(6) "359.5B"
["PreviousClose"]=>
string(6) "534.52"
["PercentageChange"]=>
string(6) "-1.13%"
["AnnRange"]=>
string(15) "487.56 - 604.83"
["Earns"]=>
string(6) "21.021"
["P-E"]=>
string(5) "25.43"
["Name"]=>
string(11) "Google Inc."
```