# How to fix "simplexml_load_file" error in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using this code to get Alexa rank in my local server. but this code isn't work when I'm upload to my server and i get errors.

**Code I'm using:**

```
$uri = 'http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=';
$uri .= $domain;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($uri);
if (isset($xml->SD[1]->COUNTRY))
$country_rate = (int) $xml->SD[1]->COUNTRY->attributes()->RANK;
return($country_rate);
```

**Errors:**

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=tooc.ir:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home2/mydesign/domains/tooc.ir/public_html/panel/2.php on line 5
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): Okay in /home2/mydesign/domains/tooc.ir/public_html/panel/2.php on line 5
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /home2/mydesign/domains/tooc.ir/public_html/panel/2.php on line 5
Notice: Undefined variable: country_rate in /home2/mydesign/domains/tooc.ir/public_html/panel/2.php on line 13
```

and here is the [link](https://panel.tooc.ir/2.php) of the sample page.

Comment: May be helpful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423902/parser-error-start-tag-expected-not-found

Comment: The response of that url seems to be just `Okay`, there is no xml.

Comment: @Jerodev but this is a xml [link](http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=tooc.ir:1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexa add my IP to the blacklist and because of it the response is "Okay".
I'm find the minisiteinfo URL and writing new code to get global and country ranking and its work fine at this time. i will put down the code if anybody have problem like me.

**CODE:**

```
function AlexaRank($domain, $country, $mode) {
    $url = "https://www.alexa.com/minisiteinfo/".$domain;
    $string = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($mode == "country") {
        $temp_s = substr($string, strpos($string, $country." Flag") + 9 + strlen($country));
        return(substr($temp_s, 0, strpos($temp_s, "</a></div>")));
    }
    else if ($mode == "global") {
        $temp_s = substr($string, strpos($string, "Global") + 38);
        return(substr($temp_s, 0, strpos($temp_s, "</a></div>")));
    }
    else {
        return('something wrong.');
    }
}


// Here how to use for country rank:
echo AlexaRank("tooc.ir", "Iran", "country");

// Here how to use for global rank:
echo AlexaRank("tooc.ir", "Iran", "global");
```